# Data storage of Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm learning on how SQL Server stores its database, tables using page and extent.

I have a simple database like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users;

CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    fname char(25) UNIQUE,
    lname char(25),
);

SET @i = 1

WHILE @i <= 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users 
    VALUES ('firstname - ' + CAST(@i as varchar(10)),
            'lastname - ' + CAST(@i as varchar(10)))

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

So basically the above code returns a table with 1000 rows, each row should have 4+25+25 = 54 bytes. However, when I use

```
DBCC showcontig('Users') with tableresults;
```

it shows that MinimumRecordSize = Maximumrecordsize = 61.

I understand that I declare fixed length value so that is why minimum=maximum, but why there are always extra 7 bytes there? I have tried with many types of data like int, bigint,...

Also, I read MS docs on page and extent but there are still a lot of confusion for me, can somebody recommend me any other source to learn how they store their data?

Comment: Why do you care?  Unless you are planning to modify SQL Server itself(???) the information is of no value as far as using it as a data store for your appliation.

Comment: Side note, your table doesn't have *records*, it has *rows*.

Comment: @SezMe No, I'm not intent to modify SQL server or anything. I just want to study how it stores its data and from what I've read in Microsoft docs, there should not be an extra 7 bytes there. It for the sake of learning only :).

Comment: Look at this link https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/sql-server-storage-internals-101/ at the storage section. The 7 additional bytes are 2 status bytes, 2 fixed-length length bytes, 2 bytes for the null bitmap length indicator and 1 byte for the null length bitmap.

Comment: Thank you @SteveFord, that explains why there are many extra bytes. I upvoted your comment.